# Objective-C: extract numeric fraction in string and convert it to a real number

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, split

I have got some strings, they look like this: 1/2 pound steak. Now I need to split the string afetr 1/2 and convert 1/2 to a number. It can be that the string contains more spaceses and 1/2 can also be 1/6 or any other number. Anyone got any idea how to split and convert?

Comment: Man what do those fractions mean?? Can you put some examples of the strings...

Comment: @JuanCatalan "They look like this: 1/2 pound steak". Also, do you know what fractions are?

Comment: @jonajürgen And you, what have you tried? SO is not here to "give you teh codez".

Comment: Sometimes is **hard** for people used to the metric system to think in fractions, bear this in mind. Now I understand the problem. Thanks for the clarification @H2CO3

Comment: @JuanCatalan Well, fair enough. Welcome. Still waiting for OP to show some code.

Comment: There are a lot of posts similar to this one in this site. I don't think we have to be harsh with novice people.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
NSString *input = @"3/4 pounds of sugar";
// trim white space at the beginning and end
input = [input stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
// define charater set to split
NSCharacterSet *chSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" /"];
// split string into array of strings by charaters '/' and ' '
NSArray *split = [input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:chSet];
// the result of the fraction inside result
double result = [split[0] doubleValue] / [split[1] doubleValue];
```